# Is using google map directions url free for commercial use?

Tags: ios, google-maps, price, directions, commercial-application

A url for example https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&travelmode=driving&origin=37.785310,-122.406096&destination=37.179518,-120.467905&waypoints=37.185310,-122.106096%7C37.279518,-121.867905%7C37.279518,-121.067905

this is opened from ios app using below code

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:routeUrlString] options:@{} completionHandler:nil];

this opens the url in google map app or browser depending on availability.

Need confirmation that it is legal and free to use this way for commercial purpose ?
A google official source url, mentions this would be really helpful

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a customer support question.

Answer (score 0):

See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/get-started.

> Using Maps URLs, you can build a universal, cross-platform URL to launch Google Maps and perform searches, get directions and navigation, and display map views and panoramic images. The URL syntax is the same regardless of the platform in use.

> **You don't need a Google API key to use Maps URLs.**

And for using directions go here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/get-started#directions-action

[image]

Comment: Actually, I am pretty much aware about no api key used and how to use, my question here is, I need official source mentioning usage of google map url as explained in question is free for commercial use